# knockoutjs subscribe not working?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using `knockoutjs` and I am new to it.  I want to change the model data based on dropdown list selected value. So in my AppModel, I am subscribing the array that i want to change. But it is not working?. Here is my code:

```
var filteredStocks  = [];
function viewModel(model) {
        this.isGeneral = ko.observable(model.generalStockEnabled);
        this.stocks = ko.observable();;
        if (model.generalStockEnabled === true)
        {
            filteredStocks = $.grep(model.stocks, function (v) {
                return v.sourceID === -1;
            });
        }
        else
        {
            filteredStocks = $.grep(model.stocks, function (v) {
                return v.sourceID !== -1;
            });
        }
        // If drop downlist changed
        var dropDownListSelectedValue = $('#enableGeneratInventorydl :selected').val();
        this.stocks.subscribe(function () {
            if (dropDownListSelectedValue === "True") {
                filteredStocks = $.grep(model.stocks, function (v) {
                    return v.sourceID === -1;
                });
                this.stocks(filteredStocks)
                this.isGeneral(true);
            }
            else
            {
                filteredStocks = $.grep(model.stocks, function (v) {
                    return v.sourceID !== -1;
                });
                this.stocks(filteredStocks)
                this.isGeneral(false);
            }
        }, this);

        this.stocks = ko.observableArray(filteredStocks);
```

when i change the drop down list value. The stocks value remain the same ?

Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem appears because you are reassigning the `stocks` variable to another observable.
So you first do:

```
this.stocks = ko.observable();
```

And then subscribe to this observable. But later you do:

```
this.stocks = ko.observableArray(filteredStocks);
```

This associates `stocks` with another observable. The subscription will be for the original observable, the one from the first assignment. 
See this fiddle for a shorter example: http://jsfiddle.net/9nGQ9/2/

The solution would be to replace `this.stocks = ko.observable();`

with `this.stocks = ko.observableArray();`

And replace `this.stocks = ko.observableArray(filteredStocks);`

with `this.stocks(filteredStocks);`